# BotFrameWork Composer - DialogManager - resourceExplorer

Tags: node.js, botframework

i got an issue when during execution of my nodeJs bot application.

/runtime/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs-declarative/lib/resources/resourceExplorer.js:261

this._declarativeTypes.forEach((component) => {
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

this is my code to load dialog from root folder:

```
private loadRootDialog() {
    const rootDialogFiles = getRootDialog(this.projectRoot);
    const rootDialogResource = this.resourceExplorer.getResource(rootDialogFiles);
    this.dialogManager = new DialogManager(this.resourceExplorer.loadType<AdaptiveDialog>(rootDialogResource));
    this.dialogManager.initialTurnState.set('settings', this.settings);
    ResourceExtensions.useResourceExplorer(this.dialogManager, this.resourceExplorer);
  }
```

Error is in ResourceExplorer class on method loadType

```
private registerComponentTypes(): void {
        if (this._typesLoaded) {
            return;
        }

        this._typesLoaded = true;

        this._declarativeTypes.forEach((component: ComponentDeclarativeTypes) => {
            component.getDeclarativeTypes(this).forEach((declarativeType: DeclarativeType) => {
                const { kind, type, loader } = declarativeType;
                this.registerTypeInternal(kind, type, loader);
            });
        });
    }
```

what i can do to solve?